# Keeping JS changes on DOM after refresh

Tags: javascript

So, I have this weird thing going on in my test site, where I have every "link" (be it menu,button, or anything) to show/hide divs instead of loading pages. Pretty basic right? Except whenever I refresh the page, it all reverts back to the Homepage, which is expected. Based on my search for answers, I think I have to use the local/session storage option. Session sounds better.

So here's the deal. I looked up the w3schools page on sessionStorage and I get how it works, but I don't undestand how I could apply this to my page. Basically every link on my page runs a function that hides the previous div and shows a new one with the content. So I was thinking if every time a function triggered, it would store a value on a var that would appoint the function as the last used. Then somehow use sessionStorage and make it work, but I can't built it. Any help?

Here's a short example of my current code.

EDITED

```
var state = null;
function show1() {
    state = "home";
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById('snow').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('btn').style.display = "none";
}


function ramble() {
    state = "ramble";
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById('ramble').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('snow').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tex').style.display = "none";
}
```

That's basically it.Onclick show/hide.

Comment: try saving it on localstorage

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Perhaps this is a more simple issue with something in there?

Comment: Based on what I've read, localstorage keeps changes after browser close and that's not something I want.

Comment: @AlexD I would but I'm currently on mobile and seems too much of a hustle to type the html, that's why I only gave some JS. I'll post some when I'm home if still needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

Save data:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Retrieve data:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

More info and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

The same goes with localStorage, but with the persistance differences you already found

Comment: That link looks really helpful, practically answers  all of my questions. I'll give it a shot and report.

Comment: So I've add a state variable that changes everytime a function is triggered. I want to build an If that depending on the state value, changes whatever needs to be changed.  Now how do I build the sessionStorage statement? Do I need to build a function and then call it? Could you perhaps give me an example, just the base of it, using the edited code I've provided, without the actions that need to be done, I'll do that myself. If that's not too much to ask.

Comment: Wait I think I got this. -- Scratch that

Comment: @Blacksteel I'll wait haha

Comment: Woops sorry I forgot to respond. Yeah I did manage to make it work but it got too complicated and I instead changed teh whole architecture to something more manageable. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I hope my solution will help you: If you want to keep your JS changes, you need to save them to **database** using **AJAX** and also change page **architecture and logic** to use data from database. After that, even if you reload page you will keep all your changes.